# How to insert Byte[] into the Informix database through the SQL Editor interface

Tags: sql, insert, arrays, rdbms, informix

I wonder if there's some way to `insert Byte[]` in to my database column using the INSERT statement through my **SQL Editor**.

For example

> INSERT INTO Temp (id,name) VALUES(1,'rg_book');

I just wanna to test my data and I don't want to make a user interface (file uploader ,...etc).

How to write this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLR Byte array type (Byte[]) maps to a VARBINARY type in Informix DB2. [See typing information here.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/r0011385.html)

If your name field is expecting character data, use the VARBINARY function to convert the data into a binary representation of the string.  [See here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_binary.htm).

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Temp (id, name) VALUES (1, VARBINARY('rg_book'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would do the following (if I've understood your question correctly):

1. Create test console project
2. Using Foreach or For (on your Byte[] array) compose required Insert's and (for example) add them to some file on a disk.
3. Run this script in Management Studio to fill in a table.

> ```
> FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"d:\Inserts.txt");
> Byte[] list = {0, 1, 2};
>
> using (StreamWriter w = f.CreateText())
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
>     {
>         w.WriteLine("INSERT INTO [TEMP] ([id], [Name]) VALUES ({0}, 'rg_book')", list[i]);
>     }
> }
> ```